# Git Bash swallows commands

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

When I enter a command into my git bash while a previous command is still running, my git bash doesnt execute it.

For example I do a 'git checkout master' and before this terminates I type 'git pull' and press enter. Now git only does the checkout and 'swallows' the pull.

The strange thing about this is when I do a git commit and nano/vi opens to edit the commit message, the git pull command that has been swallowed suddenly appears at the start of the commit message.

I already reinstalled git and installed a later version. I also deleted .bashrc and .bash_profile. Im on git for windows using minTTY.

I know for sure that in the past I could send as many commands as I want and git bash would execute them all sequentially. How do I get this behaviour back?

Comment: Are you sure the command isn't executed? My experience is that it runs the command once the other is finished.

Comment: Yes, the command isnt executed. When I do a sleep 5 and then change directory before the 5 seconds are over I stay in the same directory. (yes I made sure that the directory im changing into exists)

Comment: Experiencing the same thing recently, but had not in the past. Our infosec team is probably auto updating it and currently on 2.43.0 (latest)